# Pad block corrupted error decoding Rijndael 256 with BouncyCastle

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, rijndael

This is my decoding class, it's using Bouncycastle, Rijndael 256 decryption. I have a error on:

```
mode.doFinal(decoded, bytesProcessed);
```

Stacktrace:

```
org.bouncycastle.crypto.InvalidCipherTextException: pad block corrupted
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PKCS7Padding.padCount(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.crypto.paddings.PaddedBufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(Unknown Source)
    at com.imocom.cryptography.Decoder.decrypt(Decoder.java:71)
    at TestingLauncher.main(TestingLauncher.java:46)
```

This is the php code doing the encoding:

```
<?php 
    $string = "This is a sample string.";
    $secret = "1234567890987654321234567898765";

    $result = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                                            $secret,
                                            $string,
                                            MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                                            "1234567890123455555555555555555"
                                           ));

    echo $result."\n";

    $back = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                          $secret,
                          base64_decode($result),
                          MCRYPT_MODE_CBC,
                          "12345678999999999999999999999999");

    echo $back."\n";
    ?>
```

This is the call:

```
byte[] decoded;
decoded = decoder.decrypt(Base64.decodeBase64(encodedTextFromServer));
```

Can anyone help me, why is this happening ?

```
public class Decoder {

byte[] IV = null;
byte[] encryptionKey = null;
Cipher cipher;
SecretKeySpec key;
BlockCipher blockCipher;
ParametersWithIV _param;

PaddedBufferedBlockCipher mode;
int blockSize;

public Decoder() {

    Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());

    try {

        IV = "1234543333333333333333333333333".getBytes("UTF-8");
        encryptionKey = "12222222222222222222222222222222".getBytes("UTF-8");

        blockCipher = new CBCBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256));
        _param = new ParametersWithIV(new KeyParameter(encryptionKey), IV);
        mode = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(blockCipher);
        blockSize = blockCipher.getBlockSize();

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encodedText) {

    byte[] decoded = new byte[mode.getOutputSize(encodedText.length)];

    try {
        mode.init(false, _param);


        int bytesProcessed = mode.processBytes(encodedText, 0, encodedText.length, decoded, 0);

        mode.doFinal(decoded, bytesProcessed);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return decoded;
}
```

Comment: Thx :) added stacktrace

Comment: Where is the encrypted data coming from? Can you post the code that produces it?

Comment: Added the php code doing the encoding.

Comment: Where in your Java code do you base64-decode the input? Also, can you please add to your question the output of the PHP line: `echo $result."\n";`.

Comment: Hi :) I added all the information, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thanks. I'm surprised though, why does `encodedTextFromServer` not match `$result`?

Comment: Sorry, that's just a example of the php script. The server is returning another String than that in the script. Thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the JavaDoc of the constructor `PaddedBufferedBlockCipher` in Bouncy Castle:

> Create a buffered block cipher PKCS7 padding

However PHP by default does not use a good padding mode, instead it simply adds zero valued bytes until the end of the block is reached. This is known as `ZeroBytePadding` in Bouncy Castle.

So please use either `ZeroBytePadding`, or better, implement PKCS#7 padding in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest that you try treating your strings as hex and not as UTF-8.  For example, your IV is "81a577a68f9e94d6cc02fe23b6ee64a4".  That is 16 bytes of hex or 32 bytes of UTF-8.  An AES IV should be 16 bytes to match the block size.  I can see other errors, but I will leave those for you to find since you say this is for a class.

Comment: Hi :) Thank you for your help. Isn't my block size 32 bytes ? as declared in the constructor.

Oh, and please let me know what are the other problems you see.

Comment: Rijndael != AES. [More block sizes](http://www.bouncycastle.org/docs/docs1.5on/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/RijndaelEngine.html#RijndaelEngine%28int%29) are permitted (including 32 bytes).

Comment: Exactly, and mine is 32 bytes long.

Comment: The "256" may refer to the block size or to the key size.  What block/key sizes were used to encrypt the message?